Securing SharePoint Content: Leveraging Group IDs for Access Restrictions in Azure AI search
Architecture:
I have my data as files in SharePoint, I want to use Azure AI search to query the data but also apply security filters for document level restriction.
I created a new application which has access to that SharePoint.
I get User ID get's passed to the python code from front end, where I can get the list of groups user has access to. So I can use this Group ID's to restrict the access he has to on search with security filters.
As indexer doesn't pull these permissions into the index (Link) I need to add new field GroupsID. This field need to be populated with File groups for each files that are indexed. How can I add them to the Index, so I can restrict user access to files one has.
I Tried crawling through the file SharePoint to generate a dict of file_id's and it's associated GroupsID's. But my key is "metadata_spo_site_library_item_id", and it's not matching with the site ID, library ID, and item ID combination when I'm generating manually. Even so is it possible to update with this dict ?

What you are attempting to do is, as of this writing, not supported with Azure AI Search out of the box. From Index data from SharePoint document libraries§Limitations and considerations (emphasis mine):


SharePoint supports a granular authorization model that determines per-user access at the document level. The indexer doesn't pull these permissions into the index, and Azure AI Search doesn't support document-level authorization. When a document is indexed from SharePoint into a search service, the content is available to anyone who has read access to the index. If you require document-level permissions, you should consider security filters to trim results and automate copying the permissions at a file level to a field in the index.



Yes exactly since it is not supported directly, to use security filters.. data need to be populated as a field (here "GroupID") for each file. So I can do filtering with searchoptions as per user access.
However, I'm stuck on how to have this new column get data updated in index.

Is GroupID a string field in your document and contains a list of associated group IDs? If so, you can map through the additionalColumns as mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-sharepoint-online and create a new field in the index, reset your indexer so it can capture the changes in the definition and this should map automatically.

I have figured out the solution. You can use "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload" with your key field to update the already indexed index.
Reference here

Are you doing this via a skill on the indexer? Or a separate script after your index is populated? I'm looking to do the same thing, mind a snippet?

@user3338143
I crawl sharepoint and create python nested dict as below, I use the dict to update the index. Here for each file I need to update User and the file groups..
updt_dict = {'value': [{'@search.action': 'mergeOrUpload',
'id': '123456',
'User': 'xyz@gmail.com',
'GroupID': ['value1',
'value2',
'value3']},
{'@search.action': 'mergeOrUpload',
'id': 'abcdefg',
'User': 'xyz@gmail.com',
'GroupID': ['value1',
'value2',
'value3']}
}
python code:
requests.post(sharepoint_ep, headers=headers, json=updt_dict)

I'm using separate script after your index is populated
